# sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, tuples

I am trying  to turn a pandas DataFrame into a SQL update statement

and this is my problem part...............

```
values = tuple(zip(*filtered_data[['site_code']].values.tolist()))[0]

query = """
UPDATE govtracker
SET pending = 'TE'  
WHERE site_code = '%s')
"""
connection = engine.connect()
update_db_query = connection.execute(query, values)
```

I am trying to update a specific column called pending through an Object

and this is my traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1224, in _execute_context
cursor, statement, parameters, context
File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 547, in do_executemany
cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site- 
packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 659, in executemany
self.execute(operation, params)
File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site- 
packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 551, in execute
self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site- 
packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 490, in cmd_query
result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site- 
packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result
raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error 
in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB 
server version for the right syntax to use near 'LCAIE30089'')' at line 3

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/MyALLRefProf/MyAutomationFuncs.py", 
line 82, in <module>
update_db_query = connection.execute(query, values)
File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 982, in execute
return self._execute_text(object_, multiparams, params)
File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1155, in _execute_text
parameters,
File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1248, in _execute_context
e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1466, in _handle_dbapi_exception
util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 383, in raise_from_cause
reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 128, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1224, in _execute_context
cursor, statement, parameters, context
File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 547, in do_executemany
cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site- 
packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 659, in executemany
self.execute(operation, params)
File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site- 
packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 551, in execute
self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site- 
packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 490, in cmd_query
result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site- 
packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result
raise errors.get_exception(packet)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 
1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'LCAIE30089'')' at line 3
[SQL: 
UPDATE govtracker
SET pending = 'TE'  
WHERE site_code = '%s')
]
[parameters: [('LCAIE30089',), ('LSINI16321',)]]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

and the error in this line..........................

```
 update_db_query = connection.execute(query, values)
```

and this is my whole code............

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv
import MySQLdb
from sqlalchemy import types, create_engine


# MySQL Connection
MYSQL_USER      = 'root'
MYSQL_PASSWORD  = 'Mharooney'
MYSQL_HOST_IP   = '127.0.0.1'
MYSQL_PORT      = 3306
MYSQL_DATABASE  = 'mydb'

engine = create_engine
('mysql+mysqlconnector://'+MYSQL_USER+':'+MYSQL_PASSWORD+'@'+MYSQ 
L_HOST_IP+':'+str(MYSQL_PORT)+'/'+MYSQL_DATABASE, echo=False)

mydir = (os.getcwd()).replace('\\', '/') + '/'
all_data = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM govtracker', engine)
# .drop(['#'], axis=1)
myOutlook_inBox = pd.read_csv(r'' + mydir + 'test.CSV', usecols=['Subject', 
'Body', 'From: (Name)', 'To: (Name)'],
                          encoding='latin-1')
myOutlook_inBox.columns = myOutlook_inBox.columns.str.replace(' ', '')

#this object extract 5 chars and 5 numbers from specific column in csv
replaced_sbj_value = myOutlook_inBox['Subject']
.str.extract(pat='(L(?:DEL|CAI|SIN).\d{5})').dropna()

#this columns I want to filter in database
myOutlook_inBox["Subject"] = replaced_sbj_value
# this conditions filters and get and dublicate repeated data from outlook 
exported file
# Condition 1: any mail from mowafy to te
frm_mwfy_to_te = myOutlook_inBox.loc[myOutlook_inBox['From: 
(Name)'].str.contains("mowafy", na=False)
                                 & myOutlook_inBox['To: 
(Name)'].str.contains("te", na=False)].drop_duplicates(
keep=False)


#Condition 2: any mail from pp to mowafy
frm_pp_to_mwfy = \
myOutlook_inBox.loc[myOutlook_inBox['From:(Name)'].str.contains("Amr Mohamed 
Abuella barakat", na=False)] \
| myOutlook_inBox.loc[myOutlook_inBox['From:(Name)'].str.contains("Reham", 
na=False)] \
| myOutlook_inBox.loc[myOutlook_inBox['From:(Name)'].str.contains("Hany", 
na=False)] \
| myOutlook_inBox.loc[myOutlook_inBox['From:(Name)'].str.contains("Ossama 
Monir", na=False)] \
& myOutlook_inBox.loc[myOutlook_inBox['To:(Name)'].str.contains("mowafy", 
na=False)].drop_duplicates(keep=False)

#Condition 3: any mail from TE to mowafy
frm_te_to_mwfy = \
myOutlook_inBox.loc[myOutlook_inBox['From:(Name)'].str.contains("te", 
na=False)] & \
myOutlook_inBox.loc[myOutlook_inBox['To:(Name)'].str.contains("mowafy", 
na=False)].drop_duplicates(keep=False)

frm_mwfy_to_te.Subject

filtered_data = all_data
.loc[all_data.site_code.str.contains('|'.join(frm_mwfy_to_te.Subject))]


print(myOutlook_inBox)

all_data.replace('\n', '', regex=True)
df = all_data.where((pd.notnull(all_data)), None)
print(df)

print("Success")

print(frm_mwfy_to_te.Subject)
print(filtered_data.site_code)

values = tuple(filtered_data[['site_code']].values)

query = """
UPDATE govtracker
SET pending = 'TE'  
WHERE site_code in %s)
"""
connection = engine.connect()
update_db_query = connection.execute(query, values)
```

So how can I solve this problem..................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the values your are passing, since the sql's where condition expects a well formed tuple like

```
WHERE site_code in ('LCAIE30089', 'LSINI16321')
```

So the solution is:

1. update your values assignment to

> `values = tuple(zip(*filtered_data[['site_code']].values.tolist()]))[0]`

2. Next instead of `WHERE site_code = '%s'` use `WHERE site_code in %s`

This should work for you.
Let me know if you are stuck in any part.

Comment: thanks for your answer but it's still have the same error I'll post my whole code

Comment: Can you tell me the value of  "tuple(filtered_data[['site_code']].values)" what it prints?

Comment: Name: site_code, dtype: object
(array(['LCAIE30089'], dtype=object), array(['LSINI16321'], dtype=object))

this the output print line

Comment: can you try this => values = tuple(filtered_data[['site_code']].to_list())

Comment: I find this error 

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_list'

I think the problem it can't find the value in mysql right?

Comment: I think the data in your column site_code is something like
|     site_code     |
| ['LCAIE30089'] |
| ['LSINI16321'] |
So you just need to unpack it to a list
`values = tuple(filtered_data[['site_code']].values.tolist())`
will give you -> (['LCAIE30089'], ['LSINI16321'])
which we can convert to vanilla tuple by
`values = tuple(zip(*x))[0]`
will give you -> ('LCAIE30089', 'LSINI16321')

Comment: So where's can I add this code in my project I think I didn't understand you well
I can add this code values = tuple(zip(*x))[0]
Could you give more details please I am sorry for disturbing

Comment: So you can replace
`values = tuple(filtered_data[['site_code']].values])`
with
`values = tuple(zip(*filtered_data[['site_code']].values.tolist()]))[0]`

I have updated the answer as well

Comment: I still find the Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

as I used the line you said

values = tuple(zip(*filtered_data[['site_code']].values.tolist()))[0]

Comment: can you give me the output of this `filtered_data[['site_code']].values.tolist()`

Comment: this is the output ('LCAIE30089', 'LSINI16321')

Comment: then use `value = tuple(filtered_data[['site_code']].values.tolist())`

Comment: i already tried this but it give me this error

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''LDELM17031')' at line 3

Comment: Do one last thing
Just print the query for me, without changing anything and send here.

Comment: do you mean use print(query)?

Comment: Yes print(query)

Comment: actually this is the print of my query

UPDATE govtracker
SET pending = 'TE'  
WHERE site_code in %s

Comment: thanks alot bro it works with this query 

UPDATE govtracker
SET pending = 'DE'  
WHERE site_code = %s

Comment: if you could help me in one more thing I'll be thankful I just have posted another question just checj this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56666587/how-to-export-from-sql-database-an-xlsx-file-with-multiple-sheet-and-exporting-c