# How to export from sql database an xlsx file with multiple sheet and exporting columns using python

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, xlsxwriter

I want to export xlsx file with multiple sheets from sql database by using queries
Now I have created a three queries every query have a SELECT order for some specific data all I need now I want to export from sql database with one xlsx file but contains three sheets I new how to export data from sql database as an xlsx file but with one sheet only and this is my code

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv
import MySQLdb
from sqlalchemy import types, create_engine
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook


# MySQL Connection
MYSQL_USER      = 'root'
MYSQL_PASSWORD  = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
MYSQL_HOST_IP   = '127.0.0.1'
MYSQL_PORT      = 3306
MYSQL_DATABASE  = 'mydb'
govtracker_table = 'govtracker' # table you want to save

con = MySQLdb.connect(user=MYSQL_USER, passwd=MYSQL_PASSWORD, 
host=MYSQL_HOST_IP, db=MYSQL_DATABASE)
cursor = con.cursor()

export_frm_db_query_ssv = "SELECT id, site_code, site_name, region, 
site_type, tac_name, dt_readiness, rfs, " \
    "rfs_date, acceptance_date_opt, acceptance_date_plan, signed_sites, " 
\
    "as_built_date, as_built_status, cluster_name, 
type_standalone_colocated, " \
    "installed_type_standalone_colocated, status, pending, pending_status, 
" \
                      "problematic_details, ets_tac, region_r, 
sf6_signed_date, " \
                      "sf6_signed_comment, comment_history, on_air_owner, 
pp_owner, " \
                      "report_comment, hu_opt_area_owner, planning_owner, 
po_number, " \
                      "trigger_date, as_built_status_tr FROM %s;" % 
govtracker_table

workbook = Workbook('SSV Progress Tracker_23 May.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
for r, row in enumerate(cursor.fetchall()):
for c, col in enumerate(row):
    sheet.write(r, c, col)
workbook.close()
```

the previous code is just extracting data from my database to xlsx file in one sheet only

now I have created three queries every query should be in three different sheets

```
#SHR Phase 1 sheet SQL query
export_frm_db_query_shr_ph1 = "SELECT id, site_code, site_name, region, 
site_type, tac_name, dt_readiness, rfs, " \
    "rfs_date, huawei_1st_submission_date, te_1st_submission_date, " \
                          "huawei_2nd_submission_date, 
te_2nd_submission_date, " \
                          "huawei_3rd_submission_date, 
te_3rd_submission_date, " \
                          "acceptance_date_opt, acceptance_date_plan, 
signed_sites, " \
    "as_built_date, as_built_status, date_dt, dt_status, " \
    "shr_status, dt_planned, integeration_status, comments_snags WHERE 
site_type = 'Existing' AND " \
                          "site_type = 'New' AND region = 'Cairo' AND 
region = 'Red sea & Sinai' " \
                          "FROM %s;" % govtracker_table

#SHR Phase 2 sheet SQL query
export_frm_db_query_shr_ph2 = "SELECT id, site_code, site_name, region, 
site_type, tac_name, dt_readiness, rfs, " \
    "rfs_date, huawei_1st_submission_date, te_1st_submission_date, " \
                          "huawei_2nd_submission_date, 
te_2nd_submission_date, " \
                          "huawei_3rd_submission_date, 
te_3rd_submission_date, " \
                          "acceptance_date_opt, acceptance_date_plan, 
signed_sites, " \
    "as_built_date, as_built_status, date_dt, dt_status, " \
    "shr_status, dt_planned, integeration_status, comments_snags WHERE 
site_type = 'Existing' AND " \
                          "site_type = 'New' AND region = 'Delta' " \
                          "FROM %s;" % govtracker_table

#SHR Phase 3 sheet SQL query
export_frm_db_query_shr_ph3 = "SELECT id, site_code, site_name, region, 
site_type, tac_name, dt_readiness, rfs, " \
    "rfs_date, huawei_1st_submission_date, te_1st_submission_date, " \
                          "huawei_2nd_submission_date, 
te_2nd_submission_date, " \
                          "huawei_3rd_submission_date, 
te_3rd_submission_date, " \
                          "acceptance_date_opt, acceptance_date_plan, 
signed_sites, " \
    "as_built_date, as_built_status, date_dt, dt_status, " \
    "shr_status, dt_planned, integeration_status, comments_snags WHERE 
site_type = 'Cow' " \
                          "site_type = 'Indoor' " \
                          "FROM %s;" % govtracker_table
```

now I need to export from mydatabase by this three queries in three sheets in one xlsx file that's every query in a sheet

final thing now I want to put columns in the exported xlsx file but with changing their names and just adding colors to this columns and change the text style and how to rename the sheet name instead of the default name

I hope this would be clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas xlsxwriter, like this:

```
writer1 = pd.ExcelWriter('xlsx file name', engine='xlsxwriter')
your_dataframe1['column based conditions'].to_excel(writer1, sheet_name='name of sheet 1', index=False, startrow=0)
your_dataframe2['column based conditions'].to_excel(writer1, sheet_name='name of sheet 2', index=False, startrow=0)
your_dataframe3.to_excel(writer1, sheet_name='name of sheet 3', index=False, startrow=0) #no conditions here
```

Just make sure your data set is dataframe type. When your excel is ready type:

```
writer1.save()
```

to save it.

If you want to format dataframe header you should import:

```
import pandas.io.formats.excel
```

and type:

```
pandas.io.formats.excel.header_style
```

To format excel files you can explore openpyxl module (I don't have ready solutions) or you can import win32com.client and format sheet with VBA macro (this is pretty easy and efficent way).

Remember you need to save your writer before edit this way (writer1.save())

```
import win32com.client

workbook1 = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename='file path' + 'file_name.xlsx', ReadOnly=1)
xl.Application.Run('PERSONAL.XLSB!personal macro name')
workbook1.Close(True)
```

To rename columns easily you can use following code:

```
dataframe = dataframe.rename(index=str, columns={'ID' : 'col2','CATEGORY' : 'col1','DATE' : 'col3'})

dataframe = dataframe[['col1','col2','col3']]
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer I'll try this and I'll give you my feedback soon

Comment: I edited post a bit, make sure you save your writer before using win32com.client. :)

Comment: thanks a lot for your interests I'll check this and give you my feedack in an hour :) thanks a lot

Comment: sorry you mean that I can use pd.dataframe instead of sql queries??

Comment: could you specify your answer depend on my code I am sorry for disturbing but I am glad to help

Comment: What i can get by the discussion is @GHMarek, wants you to use pandas read_sql to fetch the data in your initial query.

Comment: @GHMarek As the the second part of your answer is the another way by exporting to xslx or it's just one way to do this

Comment: You can use whatever data type you want but my solution is  written for pd.dataframe (eg. your_dataframe3.to_excel).

Comment: So what data type is: type(export_frm_db_query_shr_ph2) ? I use pyodbc for ssms or cx_oracle to connect to sql server and import data straight to dataframe:
your_dataframe = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT ID, DATE FROM YOUR_TABLE')